# What papers detail the early research on heavy fermion superconductors?

Tags: specific-reference, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Can someone point me to the papers detailing when/where/how heavy fermion superconductors were first synthesized, tested and documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice topical review on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4114

The first heavy fermion publication was in 1978 by Steglich: http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v43/i25/p1892_1